# Is it possible to add an image icon to a nav bar in a specific view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to add an image to the nav bar? The image should be viewed only in a certain view (i.e. not throughout the application)... Example with an earth icon:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsyH8.png

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"1.bmp"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imgView];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! Same way you would add any other subView to a view.

```
[myNavBar addSubView: myIconView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the image in interface builder if you don't want to do it programmatically. Select a button in interface builder and there should be an option to use an image for that item in the Attributes Inspector under "Bar Item"

Comment: It is hard to do it in interface builder since each view does not have the navigation controller visible